# How to check GPU and motherboard compatibility?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, gpu, compatibility

I want to buy the following motherboard: [link](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Piledriver-1600mhz-Corsair-M5A78L-M-Motherboard/dp/B00FARKC56/) 
And this GPU: [link](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Nvidia-GeForce-DirectCU-GDDR5-Graphics/dp/B00DBPKEOI/)

How do I know if they are compatible?

Comment: The motherboard has a PCI-Ex16 of course it will support it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You look at the specifications of both and see if the cardslot/bus type is the same, in which case they are:

[M5A78L-M/USB3 Specs](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M5A78LMUSB3/specifications/)

1 x PCIe x16

[GTX760-DC2OC-2GD5 Specs](http://www.asus.com/Graphics_Cards/GTX760DC2OC2GD5/specifications/)

PCI Express x16 3.0

---

Just a side note, this is easily researched [on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=motherboard%20gpu%20compatibility&oq=motherboard%20gpu%20co&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.4583j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=121&ie=UTF-8).

http://smallbusiness.chron.com/determine-graphics-card-compatibility-motherboard-60636.html